# Entity revision metadata key missing after upgrading

Tags: entities, upgrading, 9

After upgrading a site to Drupal 9, I started seeing the following error when visiting  the site:

> Drupal\Core\Entity\Exception\UnsupportedEntityTypeDefinitionException: The entity type banner does not have an "revision_created" entity revision metadata key. in
> Drupal\Core\Entity\RevisionableContentEntityBase::revisionLogBaseFieldDefinitions() (line 35 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/RevisionLogEntityTrait.php).

The site has a custom entity, banner.

I rolled back to Drupal 8.9, created a module to make the same entity revisionable, and added the following code in module.install.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_update_dependencies().
 */
function mirum_entity_revision_update_dependencies() {
  // The update function that adds the status field must run after
  // content_translation_update_8400() which fixes NULL values for the
  // 'content_translation_status' field.
  if (\Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('content_translation')) {
    $dependencies['mirum_entity_revision'][8400] = [
      'content_translation' => 8400,
    ];

    return $dependencies;
  }
}

/**
 * Add the 'published' and revisionable metadata fields to banner.
 */
function mirum_entity_revision_update_8400() {
  $definition_update_manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();

  // Add the published entity key and revisionable metadata fields to the
  // banner entity type.
  $entity_type = $definition_update_manager->getEntityType('banner');
  $entity_type_id = $entity_type->id();

  $entity_keys = $entity_type->getKeys();
  $entity_keys['published'] = 'status';
  $entity_type->set('entity_keys', $entity_keys);

  $revision_metadata_keys = [
    'revision_user' => 'revision_user',
    'revision_created' => 'revision_created',
    'revision_log_message' => 'revision_log_message'
  ];
  $entity_type->set('revision_metadata_keys', $revision_metadata_keys);

  $definition_update_manager->updateEntityType($entity_type);

  // Add the status field.
  $status = BaseFieldDefinition::create('boolean')
    ->setLabel(t('Publishing status'))
    ->setDescription(t('A boolean indicating the published state.'))
    ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
    ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
    ->setDefaultValue(TRUE);

  $has_content_translation_status_field = \Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('content_translation') && $definition_update_manager->getFieldStorageDefinition('content_translation_status', $entity_type_id);
  if ($has_content_translation_status_field) {
    $status->setInitialValueFromField('content_translation_status');
  }
  else {
    $status->setInitialValue(TRUE);
  }
  $definition_update_manager->installFieldStorageDefinition('status', $entity_type_id, $entity_type_id, $status);

  // Add the revision metadata fields.
  $revision_created = BaseFieldDefinition::create('created')
    ->setLabel(t('Revision create time'))
    ->setDescription(t('The time that the current revision was created.'))
    ->setRevisionable(TRUE);
  $definition_update_manager->installFieldStorageDefinition('revision_created', $entity_type_id, $entity_type_id, $revision_created);

  $revision_user = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
    ->setLabel(t('Revision user'))
    ->setDescription(t('The user ID of the author of the current revision.'))
    ->setSetting('target_type', 'user')
    ->setRevisionable(TRUE);
  $definition_update_manager->installFieldStorageDefinition('revision_user', $entity_type_id, $entity_type_id, $revision_user);

  $revision_log_message = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string_long')
    ->setLabel(t('Revision log message'))
    ->setDescription(t('Briefly describe the changes you have made.'))
    ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
    ->setDefaultValue('')
    ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
      'type' => 'string_textarea',
      'weight' => 25,
      'settings' => [
        'rows' => 4,
      ],
    ]);
  $definition_update_manager->installFieldStorageDefinition('revision_log_message', $entity_type_id, $entity_type_id, $revision_log_message);

  // Uninstall the 'content_translation_status' field if needed.
  $database = \Drupal::database();
  if ($has_content_translation_status_field) {
    // First we have to remove the field data.
    $database->update($entity_type->getDataTable())
      ->fields(['content_translation_status' => NULL])
      ->execute();

    // A site may have disabled revisionability for this entity type.
    if ($entity_type->isRevisionable()) {
      $database->update($entity_type->getRevisionDataTable())
        ->fields(['content_translation_status' => NULL])
        ->execute();
    }

    $content_translation_status = $definition_update_manager->getFieldStorageDefinition('content_translation_status', $entity_type_id);
    $definition_update_manager->uninstallFieldStorageDefinition($content_translation_status);
  }

  return t('@entity_type_label has been converted to revisionable and publishable.', ['@entity_type_label' => $entity_type->getLabel()]);
}
```

I activated the module and upgraded again to Drupal 9, but the error persists.

I am using Drush and Composer but because of this error with the entity, none of the Drush commands work.

For example, running `drush cr` returns the following error.

> The entity type banner does not have an "revision_created" entity revision metadata key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set the missing metakey already in the update hook, but this is not stored in the entity definitions permanently, this is only temporary for the update process:

```
  $revision_metadata_keys = [
    'revision_user' => 'revision_user',
    'revision_created' => 'revision_created',
    'revision_log_message' => 'revision_log_message'
  ];
  $entity_type->set('revision_metadata_keys', $revision_metadata_keys);
```

For this you need to include them in the entity annotations:

*/mymodule/src/Entity/Banner.php*

```
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "banner",
 *   ...
 *   revision_metadata_keys = {
 *     "revision_user" = "revision_user",
 *     "revision_created" = "revision_created",
 *     "revision_log_message" = "revision_log_message",
 *   },
```

Then the command `drush cr` should update the entity definition without error.

Comment: may you please clarify, which file do I add this snippet to? does this go somewhere in the new module I created inside the .install file, or do I add it somewhere in the existing banner module?

Comment: In the annotations of the entity class, see the edit. Didn't you work on that class while making the entity revisionable?

Comment: no #4k4. I already found the class when given the site. So the entity was created through a module since Drupal 8.6.16.

Comment: OK, my answer is for the error message. You probably need to change more things in the entity class to make it revisionable, but perhaps it is already and only the metadata is missing. Who knows :-).

Comment: The fields are revisionable because there is a method(setRevisionable) set to true on all fields. But when I check the database table, the banner table does not have the revision_created attribute. Am thinking of adding it through a sql query but am not sure what the data type it is nor if its a recommended approach.

Comment: Don't change database tables on your own. Let the update hook do the database schema updates. The first thing you need to do, though, is to get the entity class right, which you can test by installing the entity on a different site, then you don't need any update hooks.